# Java - How can I check if Facebook app is running as foreground on Android using service?

Tags: java, android

I am currently working on an app that works like setting a passcode on the Facebook app. Whenever a user enters Facebook, I want my service to know that Facebook is being opened and will overlap Facebook with my app's UI.